# Android how to get router name?

Tags: android, wifi, router

I need to known router's name.
I read some relevant information not find method。
any way to get it？
For example router name's:TP_Link. how to get it's name?

Comment: where is the router? what permissions do you have regarding the router? and do you mean SSID because I believe getting router name depends on the router setting. If it is advertising its name you cant know it.

Comment: You could just by the router a drink and ask it?

Comment: Do you mean Wifi network name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out the model of the router you should have a database of MAC addresses(first half - xx:xx:xx...) and manufacturers. I found rather big base in text form http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt. For example WiFi Analyzer use [this db](http://rghost.ru/66drq9ccn) (taken from WiFiAnalyzer.apk/res/raw/ieee_oui.db)

Comment: latest version [here](https://yadi.sk/d/P8rHxrC2vB8fP) from [wireshark.org](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html). If you want create db yourself, you can use my [python script](https://yadi.sk/d/BRJ_8xvIvB8iV), but file must contains lines like "XX:XX:XX:XX Manufacturer" or "XX-XX-XX Manufacturer" etc, **Sublime Text** can help you for solution to this problem

Answer (score 3):

You will get **WiFi network details** (name etc.) from below code snippet :

```
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   Log.d("wifiInfo", wifiInfo.toString());
   Log.d("SSID",wifiInfo.getSSID());
```

Don't forget to add permission in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: I think you understand what I mean.  wifiInfo.getSSid is  wifi's name and not router's name(router brand).The access point is similar to the         WiFi Analyzer in the list